# Displaying a PHP page inside an other php page with DIV and passing a dynamic variable to url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am able to display the second php page into my first php page inside my DIV tag.
The problem is that the user has to select a number from a drop down list and then click on SUBMIT button. When user click on submit it will display the second php page by loading the second.php?test=$vr . But it doesnt work as $vr is passed incorrectly.

IN SHORT: I am unable to pass the selected number to the url in the script.

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
$('#SubmitForm').submit(function( event ) {

$.ajax({
        $val = $_POST['test'];
        url: 'second.php?index=$vr',  ///second.php?index=1 <- this works but i need a var because its dynamic.
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $('#SubmitForm').serialize(),
        success: function(content)
        {
            $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
        }  
});

event.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

drop list which user has select and then click on edit

```
<div id="page">
    <form id="SubmitForm" method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
         <div id="SubmitDiv">
            <select name="index" required>
            <?php
            while($t = $results->fetchArray()){
                echo '<option value="'.$t.'">'.$c.'</option>';  
            }
            ?>
            </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">edit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="DisplayDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Want to add a screenshot for the page to make it more easy to visualize?

Comment: well its just a drop list with numbers. i just need to pass the variable correctly to the url in my script JS.

Answer (score 0):

First give your select box an ID tag, this allows you to easily access the value the user has selected e.g.:

```
<div id="page">
    <form id="SubmitForm" method="post" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
         <div id="SubmitDiv">
            <select id="myselect" name="index" required>
            <?php
            while($t = $results->fetchArray()){
                echo '<option value="'.$t.'">'.$c.'</option>';  
            }
            ?>
            </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">edit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="DisplayDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then change your ajax query to:

```
var foo = $("#myselect").val(); // this is the value selected by user
$.ajax({
    url: 'second.php',
    data: {
        index: foo
    },
    success: function(content)
    {
        $("#DisplayDiv").html(content);
    }  
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked :) I am having problem understanding, sometimes I use name tag to store a value but here we used an id ?

Comment: No problem. :) With ID tags, you can pick out values from anywhere in your page via JS but you have to be careful with what you name them as they have to all be unique. Name tags are used within forms and allow you to access values when the whole form is submitted to the server; duplicates don't matter as long as they are in separate forms.